# vue-datepicker to disable before and from

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am attempting to set a range of dates to allow users to pick the date using vue-datepicker, since desktop safari users have problems using input type date. Going thru the documentation of vue-datepicker and looking at the demo it has, I got really confused. Where do I apply the disable data to limit the range of dates on the datepicker dropdown?

I have tried to put the :disabled="disabled" in datepicker, but documentation says it expects a boolean response. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<template>
    <div>
        <datepicker v-model="booking_date"></datepicker>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            moment: moment,
            booking_date: null,
            disabled: {},
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.defaultDateRange();
    },
    methods: {
        defaultDateRange() {
            let tzoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
            let today = (new Date(Date.now() - tzoffset)).toISOString().substr(0, 10);
            let max = new Date();
            max.setDate(max.getDate() + 30);
            let max_date = max.toISOString().substr(0, 10);
            this.disabled = {
                to: Date.parse(today),
                from: Date.parse(max_date)
            };
            this.booking_date = Date.parse(today);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

new attempt:

```
<datepicker v-model="booking_form.booking_date" :disabled-dates="disabled"></datepicker>
```

Comment: After working a below code worked for me. Could you please check once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a lot the following code worked for me(In which datepicker disabled all the dates which come after 1 month from present as well as all previous dates). I have used **ranges** as mentioned in **datepicker** documentation [datepicker npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker)

template:::

```
<datepicker :disabledDates="disabledDates" ></datepicker>
```

script::::

```
import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
export default {
    data(){
      return {
        disabledDates:{
           ranges:[]
        }
      }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defaultDateRange();
  },
  components:{
       Datepicker
  },
  methods:{
       let tzoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
       let today = (new Date(Date.now() - tzoffset));

       let oldToday = new Date(today.getTime()); // AS DATES ARE REFRENCE COOPIED I HAD TO COPY THE VALUE OF TODAY 
       oldToday.setDate(oldToday.getDate()-1);

       today.setMonth(today.getMonth()+1); // GETTING NEXT MONTHS DATE

       let max = new Date(); // YOU CAN REMOVE THIS MAX VARIABLE I JUST PUT IT FOR YOUR REFRENCE
       let obj = {};
       max.setDate(max.getDate() + 30);
       let max_date = max;

       obj["from"] = new Date(0,0,0); // FOR DISABLING ALL PREVIOUS DATES I PUT THIS IN RANGES ARRAY INSIDE DISABLEDDATES OBJECT
       obj["to"] = oldToday;

       this.disabledDates["ranges"].push(obj);
       this.disabledDates["from"] = today;
       console.log("disableDates is ");
       console.log(this.disabledDates);
       this.booking_date = Date.parse(today);
  }
}
```

Comment: yes this works for disabling 1 month from now, but my requirement is to disable every date except for the next 1 month, when I swap the "to" and "from", the disable does not work anymore. I also tried changing "range" to "disabledDates" like the documentation, and it does not disable any dates before today and after 30 days.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and adapted changes and it worked! You have been a great help! "ranges" has been removed and i added directly this.disabled["from"] = max; this.disabled["to"] = today;

Answer (score 0):

To omit certain dates out of the selectable ones, you should `disabled-dates` attribute  (not `disabled`) as:

```
<datepicker v-model="booking_date" :disabled-dates="disabled"></datepicker>
```

And you can then set `disabled` convention in your `data` section which you apparently already did in your js code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The property is called disabledDates, you can read more about it in the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#disabled-dates).

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h3gkqc4w/

```html
<div id="app">
  <d-p
     v-model="model.date"
     :format="DatePickerFormat"
     :disabled-dates="disabledDates">
</d-p>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components:{'d-p': vuejsDatepicker},
  data: {
    model: {
          date: ''
        },
        DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        disabledDates: {
          to: new Date(Date.now())
        }
  }
})
```

Comment: i got error: TypeError: date.getMonth is not a function & TypeError: date.getFullYear is not a function. my data declaration is a little different from yours i do a data(){return{disabled:{}}},

Comment: hi I have added the changes and got the error for date.getMonth is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
                   <!--First Date-->
                      <VCol cols="12" md="3">
                        <AppDateTimePicker
                          v-model="formData.first_date"
                          label="First Date"
                          :config="{ dateFormat: 'd/m/Y' }"
                          placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                          clearable
                          clear-icon="tabler-x"
                          :rules="
                          myStore.currentStep === 0 ? [requiredValidator] : []"
                          @click:clear="clearDate"
                        />
                      </VCol>
                      <VSpacer />

                      <!--Second Date-->
                      <VCol cols="12" md="3">
                        <AppDateTimePicker
                          v-if="isDisable"
                          v-model="formData.second_date"
                          label="Second Date"
                          :config="{ dateFormat: 'd/m/Y' }"
                          placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                          disabled
                        />

                        <AppDateTimePicker
                          v-else
                           v-model="formData.second_date"
                           label="Second Date"
                          :config="{ dateFormat: 'd/m/Y' }"
                          placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                          clearable
                          clear-icon="tabler-x"
                        />
                      </VCol>
```

Use simple v-if and v-else for disabled date picker in Vuetify3 or later.
Thank You, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="date" id="datemin" name="datemin" min="currentDateWithFormat">
<script>
      var currentDate = new Date();
      var currentDateWithFormat = new Date()
        .toJSON()
        .slice(0, 10)
        .replace(/-/g, "-");
      console.log(currentDateWithFormat);
</script>
```